# Java servlet cannot read an html select tag name

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I am currently working on dynamically adding table rows with select boxes and getting the values of the added select boxes in a servlet. The addition of the select box is working and it is fine but when I get the values of the select boxes that are added dynamically in a servlet, the values become null. This is the code that I have as of now:

Javascript:

```
function addCreditRow(tableID) {               
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);               
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;  
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); 
    var count = rowCount+1;

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("select");
    element1.name = "credAcc"+count;  //*** EDIT ***
     <%for(int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++){%>
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", "<%=aList.get(i).getAccount_name()%>");
        option.innerHTML = "<%=aList.get(i).getAccount_name()%>";
        element1.appendChild(option);
        <%}%>
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
    document.getElementById("cred").value=count;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);             
    var element = document.createElement("input");             
    element.type = "text";
    element.name = "credAmt"+count;     //*** EDIT ***
    cell2.appendChild(element);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pull-right">
<INPUT type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Add A Credit Account" onclick="addCreditRow('credTable')" />
                                        </div>
<input type="hidden" name="credit" id="cred" value="1">
                                           <br><br>

                                           <table class="table">
                                            <thead>
                                           <tr>
                                               <th>Account</th>
                                               <th>Amount</th>
                                             </tr>
                                               </thead>
                                           </table>
                                               <table class="table" id="credTable">
                                               <tbody>
                                           <tr>

                                                       <td><select name="credAcc1">
                                                   <%for(int i = 0 ; i < aList.size(); i++){%>
                                                   <option value="<%=aList.get(i).getAccount_name()%>"><%=aList.get(i).getAccount_name()%></option>
                                                   <%}%>
                                                   </select></td>
                                               <td><input type="text" name="credAmt1"></td>
                                           </tr>
                                               </tbody>
                                           </table>
```

Java Servlet:

```
int credit = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("credit"));
        ArrayList<String> credList = new ArrayList();

        for(int x = 1; x < credit+1; x++){
            credList.add(request.getParameter("credAcc"+x));
        }

        ServletContext context= getServletContext();
        request.setAttribute("credList", credList);
            RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/newjsp.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

JSP page where I show the values stored in the ArrayList:

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<HTML> 
<%

ArrayList<String> credList = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("credList");
%>
<HEAD>     
<TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>     


</HEAD> 

<BODY>

<form name="myform" action="myServlet" method="post">



    <h1>CREDIT ACCOUNTS:</h1><br>
    <%for(int i = 0; i < credList.size(); i++){%>
    <h2><%=credList.get(i)%></h2><br>
    <%}%>

</form>

</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

Is there something wrong with my javascript function?

Comment: what do you mean `the values become null. ` . In your html or when you get the values in the servlet?

Comment: And where is the code that you post the data to the servlet?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy queston edited. I already added the jsp code where I show the values of the arraylist

Comment: in the code `ArrayList<String> credList = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("credList");` what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Dont fully understand your question, but there is a good likelyhood you meant to add options in JSP scriptlet which is not showing up in your HTML.. from your code. If that were the case, the way you create Options can be this way in your addCreditRow function:

```
try{
    t1.add( new Option( name , value  ) );
}catch( e ){
    t1.add( new Option( name , value ), null );
}
```

What this does is attempts to create Option with the first new operator with standard two parameters and if it fails, which it will for some browsers, will create with three parameters.